# equivalent command `route -n` in BSD

Tags: route, bsd

Command `route -n` of BSD return nothing

```
$ route -n
usage: route [-dnqtv] command [[modifiers] args]
```

It's output of GNU version

[image]

What's the equivalent in BSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `netstat -rn` for this purpose.

See the FreeBSD man page on [netstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE) for more details.

Incidentally, that also works in Linux, so in a way it's a more portable command than `route -n` to inspect the routing tables.

Answer (score 3):

On OpenBSD and NetBSD:

```
route -n show
```

You forgot to mention the task that you wanted `route` to do: `show`.  This is also hinted at in the error message that you get.

The Linux `route` command and the `route` commands on the different BSD systems are pretty different in their semantics, and the BSD command does not default to showing the routes.  The `route` implementations on FreeBSD and macOS require a specific destination address.  You would be better off using `netstat -rn` on those two systems.